# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'search' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, referenceerror

**I keep getting this reference error and no idea what is wrong.**

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'search' before initialization
App
C:/Users/GS66/Desktop/IN20/IFN666/week4/src/App.js:60
57 |
58 | export default function App() {
59 |

> 60 |   const { loading, headlines, error } = useNewsArticles(search);
> 61 |   const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
> 62 |
> 63 |   if (loading) {

**This is the App part in App.js**

```
export default function App() {
const {loading, headlines, error} = useNewsArticles(search);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
}
if (error) {
    return <p>Something went wrong: {error.message}</p>
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>News Headlines</h1>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch}/> {
            headlines.map((headline) => (
                //headline is now an object
                <Headline key={headline.url} title={headline.title}/>
            ))
        }
    </div>
);
```

}

**And this is the useNewsArticles function part from api.js.**

```
export function useNewsArticles(search) {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [headlines, setHeadlines] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
        try {
            setHeadlines(await getHeadlines(search));
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(error);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    })();
}, [search]);

    return {
        loading,
        headlines,
        error,
    };

}
```

Comment: Not sure what to say because the error says it all: you are using `search` before you define it, which happens one line further down... The `:60` in the error means line 60 so this way you know which line the error is talking about

Comment: You're using search in line 2. You initialize search in line 3.

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing search in line 3 and using in line 2. You should do the reverse, like

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const {loading, headlines, error} = useNewsArticles(search);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you're trying to use a variable before declaring it.

First declare `search` with `useState()` then use it as a hook param.